# Error coming every time I try to run my code

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the error that I am receiving every time I try and run my code:

```
Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\ncid1\OneDrive\Desktop\Boblox\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling the package (better-sqlite3)

```
npm uninstall better-sqlite3
```

And then reinstall it

```
npm install better-sqlite3
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out kind sir. I wish you the best on your coding journey!

Comment: Glad to help. I wish you success on your future as well